# Why time is printed same in code for IPC

Tags: c, ipc

I have written a code to understand the IPC and the basic of read, write function.
As read function is blocking, read will wait till data is written on the other end of pipe by other process.
I have make sleep call before write() in parent process. And in child process before and after read() i have printed time.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int fd[2], err, pid;
    FILE *fp;
    char *buf;

    buf = malloc(12);
    fp = fopen("BE1.txt","w");
    err = pipe(fd);
    if(err == -1)
        printf("Error while creating pipe");
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == -1)
        printf("Error while creating process");
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        fprintf(fp,"before read %s\n", __TIME__);
        //    fflush(fp);
        read(fd[0], buf, 12);
        fprintf(fp,"%s\n", buf);
        //   fflush(fp);
        fprintf(fp,"after read %s\n", __TIME__);
    }
    else
    {
        sleep(50);
        write(fd[1], "this is it", 12);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

As read is in blocking mode, child process should print different time in the code above.
But it prints same time as

## output:

```
before read 19:48:16
this is it
after read 19:48:16
```

Why this is so?

Comment: Sleep sleeps for the specified _milli_seconds...

Comment: Try `sleep(5000)` to get a visual difference...

Comment: sleep is in seconds. before terminating , program waits for about minute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__TIME__` is a predefined `#define` macro which is evaluated at compile time, i.e. when the compiler sees `__TIME__`, he will replace it with the current time.

The gcc documentation says:

> `__TIME__`
>
> This macro expands to a string constant that describes the time at which the preprocessor is being run. The string constant contains eight characters and looks like `"23:59:01"`.
>
> If GCC cannot determine the current time, it will emit a warning message (once per compilation) and `__TIME__` will expand to `"??:??:??"`.

Comment: if it replace with current time, then after read call, time should be replaced with current time??

Comment: @Ajay: No. Is your problem maybe that you come from a (usually) interpreted language like Python, PHP or so? If so: When C++ code is compiled, it is compiled into a fixed binary. The compiler will replace _at the time of compilation_ that macro with _the time of compilation_.

Answer (score 3):

```
__TIME__
```

defines the time of the compilation !

Answer (score 3):

`__TIME__`, like `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`, is a preprocessor macro that expands to the time *when the preprocessor was run* (usually as part of the compiler). So, it's a fixed string -- your code will end up compiled like

```
fprintf(fp,"after read %s\n", "19:49:16");
```

depending on exactly when you compiled the code.

For timing an operation, use `clock` instead.

Answer (score 1):

to add to all the excellent answers above:

if you want to print time, then how about :

```
void printCurrentTime()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  char buffer [80];

  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );

  strftime (buffer,80,"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S",timeinfo);
  puts (buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already, `__TIME__` is evaluated at compile time not runtime.

If you want the actual time at runtime, you'll need to use something like: -

```
 time_t t;
 time(&t);
 printf("%s", ctime(&t));
```

There are other ways of printing the time and ways of getting different formats.

PS. You'll need to include time.h